# AdSense Ad Refresh

Tags: adsense

I have a question; I have a blog hosted on WordPress, so I want to refresh ads (not refresh the entire page, just the ads) every 10 to 15 seconds through a premium plug. Do you think it is something that google allows? Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google does not allow Adsense Ad refresh, It is a violation.

Comment: Not even if we're just refreshing an ad unit not the page?

Comment: Adunit not on the page? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Like refreshing the ad slot, I am not talking about refreshing the entire page.

Comment: Yes, that is what i have mentioned above, You can not refresh Adsense ads. Beside if you use an ADX Partner they can setup adrefresh for you, As they are allowed to use Refreshing technologies like DFP. Also the recommended minimum adrefresh time is 30 seconds

Comment: You should actually add a source to the policy.